# What is the difference of 犯不着 用不着 and 犯不上？

Tags: difference

why in this sentence is 犯不着?
e.g.
犯不着为这点小事生气。
when you use it? why not “用不着”“犯不上”?
it's idiomatic ?
can you give me example sentences?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

[犯不着/犯不上]为这点小事生气。 oral chinese

用不着为这点小事生气。mostly we use this way in written.

they are all ok. and the meanings of 犯不着/犯不上/用不着 are almost the same. it's up to you.

Comment: Are these sentences correct?                                                                                                           1.犯不着为这点小事生气=犯不上为这点小事生气=用不着为这点小事生气                                          2.你们用不着带伞=你们犯不着带伞=你们犯不上带伞                                                                        3.我们用不着扳手=我们犯不着扳手=我们犯不上扳手

Comment: right or wrong?

Comment: @jinglingmen 2、3 can only use 用不着 in that case.【犯不着/犯不上】use to comfort others when they're angry/upset.  【用不着】 means just no need.

Answer (score 0):

犯不着/犯不上 = not worth

Example: **犯不着**親自冒險 (**not worth** taking the risk personally)

~

用不着 = no need to

Example: **用不着**親自冒險 (**no need to** take the risk personally)

~

犯 = to involve

犯不着 = not at the point of involving yourself = not worth

用 = need

用不着 = not at the point of need to = no need to

着/上 is a verb particle that indicates 'completion' or 'result' of the verb

**Edit:**

Although 犯不着/上 (not worth) and 用不着 (no need to) mean different things. They are sometimes interchangeable when the reason for 'no need to do something is 'not worth (wasting time and energy)' -- when doing something you don't need to do is a waste of time and energy

On the other hand, the reason for '用不着' (no need to) **might not be** '犯不着'(not worth doing). It might be 1.'it will be done by someone else 2.'it has been done' 3.'it is not important' So, you can replace 犯不着 with 用不着 when you meant to say 'not worth', but you cannot replace 用不着 with 犯不着 if you didn't mean 'not worth'

你们用不着带伞 cannot be changed to 你们犯不着带伞 or 你们犯不上带伞 because 'no need to bring umbrella' simply means an umbrella is not needed (it is not raining and will not rain during the trip). carry an umbrella is not much of a waste of time and energy-- but getting angry is. Therefore, 犯不着为这点小事生气, 犯不上为这点小事生气, and 用不着为这点小事生气 are all correct and mean the same thing

Comment: Are these sentences correct? 1.犯不着为这点小事生气=犯不上为这点小事生气=用不着为这点小事生气 2.你们用不着带伞=你们犯不着带伞=你们犯不上带伞 3.我们用不着扳手=我们犯不着扳手=我们犯不上扳手

Comment: @ jinglingmen See my edition at the bottom

Comment: Thank you! It’s very helpful!